# Location Manager not working if gps is on.Its working fine if gps is of

Tags: android, gps, android-location

In my code when layout loads it fetch gps coordinate .This is my sample code. It works fine if GPS is off. If i turn on the gps its not loading the gps coordinates . I need to get user gps coordinates when he turn on GPS. so what is the problem . where i need to change. Sorry for my English.

```
 dialog = new ProgressDialog(FXPage.this);
  dialog.show();
  dialog.setMessage("Getting Coordinates");

  locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  if (locationManager
          .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
      LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 100000000,
      1, this);
      } else if (locationManager
              .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
      LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 100000000,
      1, this);
      }
      else {
          dialog.dismiss();

          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enable Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
```

---

```
 protected void refresh() {

           super.onResume();
           this.recreate();

        }

     @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.show();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude =location.getLongitude();
            if (latitude != 0 && longitude != 0){

            edittext6.setText(location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude());

            dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

     @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. GPS dosen't works under roof.
2. You can get Location updates from Network provider first if its available.
3. If N/A then only request it from GPS and start a CountDownTimer
4. Now after timer expires u can check if the location is still null then Alert user "unable to get location update" and stop the GPS location update request.

to Avoid all above trouble you may simply want to use FusedLocation Api which work better than the previous LocationApi.
check [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) link for FusedLocation api.

Comment: @benarjee bojja: Its der in the link. Plz take an effort to try it urself first or may search for a tutorial and if none help I sure will :)

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code seems to be really strange:

```
 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dialog.show();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude =location.getLongitude();
        if (latitude != 0 && longitude != 0){

        edittext6.setText(location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude());

        dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Basically you are showing and then immediately dismissing a dialog. Maybe you should use a timer to dismiss the dialog after coordinates are shown.

Here are some good advices to get a single location update.

First of all check that the GPS is enabled, this will make your workflow more robust:

```
final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

    if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
        buildAlertMessageNoGps();
    }

  private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                   startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Then before asking the *LocationManager* for new location updates I would check if there is a good enough "last known location" (this obviously depends on the precision you need).
For example you can iterate through each location provider to find the most timely and accurate last known location as shown here:

```
List<String> matchingProviders = locationManager.getAllProviders();
for (String provider: matchingProviders) {
  Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
  if (location != null) {
    float accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
    long time = location.getTime();

    if ((time > minTime && accuracy < bestAccuracy)) {
      bestResult = location;
      bestAccuracy = accuracy;
      bestTime = time;
    }
    else if (time < minTime && 
             bestAccuracy == Float.MAX_VALUE && time > bestTime){
      bestResult = location;
      bestTime = time;
    }
  }
}
```

If the last known location is not recent enough you may request a single location update using the fastest location provider available:

```
if (locationListener != null &&
   (bestTime < maxTime || bestAccuracy > maxDistance)) { 
  IntentFilter locIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(SINGLE_LOCATION_UPDATE_ACTION);
  context.registerReceiver(singleUpdateReceiver, locIntentFilter);      
  locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, singleUpatePI);
}
```

Obviously you need to configure a *BroadcastReceiver*:

```
protected BroadcastReceiver singleUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.unregisterReceiver(singleUpdateReceiver);

    String key = LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED;
    Location location = (Location)intent.getExtras().get(key);

    if (locationListener != null && location != null)
      locationListener.onLocationChanged(location);

    locationManager.removeUpdates(singleUpatePI);
  }
};
```